# What does 'I would be up for it?' mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

When I suggest someone a plan, that person usually answers saying 'I would be up for it.' What does it mean? does it mean 'I am available?'

Comment: It means they would be willing to do "it". Another way they could say that would be "Count me in."

Comment: Just to confuse things more: "I'd be up for that" means "I'm down with that." ;-)

Answer (score 2):

It means "I would be willing to do what you proposed."

Comment: To add, it implies that they are also keen to do it as well